# Is it ok to edit and add an author's own content to their post, eg. from a comment or from the post to the title?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I wouldn't neccessarily complain just for having an edit rejected - after all, maybe I *thought* I was being helpful but others disagreed. That's ok.

Today though I had two edits rejected where it seemed that the reviewer(s) misunderstood what I was trying to do.

I'm not entirely sure whether I shouldn't have been doing this, or whether the reviewers were jumping through quickly without looking at the post in detail first.

The two edits:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12323323
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12280696

In both these cases, the reasons for rejections would make complete sense if I had just randomly added this text myself. However in the first one, I took this text directly from the author's comment on his post (which I thought would've made more sense - and given more visibility - as an edit to an otherwise sparse post), and the second I simply clarified the title of the post (to make it easier to find/sort) based on what the asker had clearly mentioned twice within the post.

So I guess my question is: while I know I shouldn't add my own content to someone else's post, is it ok to add *that author's own content* when it clarifies the post? On reflection I would probably say I can understand why the first edit was rejected, but the second seems to me to be entirely useful.

By the way, I will pay more attention to edit summaries for posts like this!

Comment: I do notice that your first edit comment specifically called out that it was the author's own clarifying comment that fleshed out the details of what was a very short answer. The second one could have used that kind of information in the edit comment. I'm somewhat surprised that first was rejected, but not entirely. It was a 3/2 decision after all.

Comment: "with Postman"suggestion has slippery [meta-tag:edit-summary], "Clarify problem in post title" - this could confuse reviewers. Something like this would be safer: "title changed to better fit question text" or "expanded title with details from question text"

Comment: Thanks guys - I agree, I will pay more attention to edit summaries for posts like this!

Comment: Note that reviewers _only_ see the suggested edit (the stuff in those links you posted) and your edit comment, they don't see the comments or other stuff on the page unless they go looking for it, which takes time, so you really need to make edit comments crystal clear, with enough context so reviewers know where you're coming from.

Comment: (cont) Actually, it's a good idea to prompt the OP to add the stuff to the post themself, and only resort to making an edit if the author doesn't respond (either because they're off line, or they just don't get how SO works). Also, when you make an edit please try to fix everything that you can, especially when that action requires approval by 3 other people.

Comment: It's fine to do this; particularly if your attitide is *"Dude, your comment was so incisive I put that info in your answer - good one bra!"*.  Don't forget however that ***nothing in the universe is more intensely annoying that anyone editing your writing for any reason***.  If that's not clear, allow me to put it this way ***nothing in the universe is more intensely annoying that anyone editing your writing for any reason*** - heh. Try to edit *with a light hand* and try to be *socially gracious* when doing so. You're brand new on the site, I don't see a compelling need for u to edit stuff...

Comment: ...so when you do edit someone's writing (the particular case you mention is fine) if possible try to do so with a socially-acceptable attitude.  Pretend you're actually with the real person - ideally in a bar.  It never hurts to drop in a comment "Great post buddy I edited in some info that improves it even more" or whatever.

Comment: (See what I mean?  :) )

Comment: Thanks guys - appreciate your guidance :)

Comment: @JoeBlow I only just happened to come back to this post and saw a line I thought I never put there. Completely missed that. Nice work :P

Comment: so long as everyone's happy!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, if an author comments on their own content with clarification or more pertinent details (in response to a comment requesting clarification, for example), then that author's comment **should** be merged in with the answer.

Comments are transient; they may not stick around forever. Good Questions and Answers should stick around until they're proven wrong or terrible quality. If part of a Question or Answer is in the form of a comment, it belongs with that Question or Answer, instead.

Once the content has been added, the comment can be flagged as Obsolete and deleted.

Your first edit is good; that content belongs in the question. Your second edit is a little superfluous as it stands, and largely incomplete; the content is already in the question, and you didn't fix any of the grammatical issues in the post.

Comment: Thank you Tyler, this helps me understand it clearly. I'll consider resubmitting both edits, with further fixes for the second one.

Comment: @TimMalone No need; I've already made edits in the spirit of what you attempted previously.

Comment: Oh, perfect! Thx v much

Comment: Obviously new information should be in the question, but shouldn't we be teaching new users to use the `edit` link?  Or is teaching by example a better way in your experience?  (i.e. make the edit, and explain in the edit message or in a separate comment that the OP should have done it themselves?)  I feel like making that a habit would lead to doing a lot of busy-work, and I'd only want to do that to help a question I like.  I'd rather down-vote a marginal question if I think the OP isn't making an effort to fit in to the community, and the question is nothing special.

Comment: Of course, if it looks like the OP is trying to engage with the people trying to help, then sure, I'll guide them towards doing things the SO way, and help salvage their question.  I just haven't done that by editing their comments into their question for them.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I'd not necessarily do that for the writer of the question, but rather for the next readers of the question ;-)

Comment: @PeterCordes It's up to you how you want to educate users/respond to posts that aren't up to your standards. Sometimes I'll let the user know why I moved their comments into the post, or why I edited it, and sometimes I'll just do it silently. The goal is to make the question better for the *site*, along the lines of what zx485 said ^. That it helps or educates the poster is ancillary.

Comment: I've found that adding a link to the comment I'm quoting in my edit description helps... assuming I have enough characters for it as well as the description.  That makes it easier for reviewers to see I'm not making things up.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, with caveats.

I've added comments to an answer where the original answer was a more of a comment, but the actual answer was a reply to the asker's comment on the "answer." That edit was accepted.
Moving important information that improves the answer, or turns it into an actual answer can be done.

If the comment being moved into the answer/question isn't improving the answer/question substantially, I would leave a comment and let the poster make the choice to edit or not. The degree of "substantial improvement" is going to vary from person to person. Try to make it as much of an improvement as you can for a suggested edit.

Though, there is also a reject reason of:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no
>   sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an
>   answer.

So, the approval of my edit moving the answer out of the comment and into the answer was narrowly approved 3 approvals to 2 rejections. Your mileage may vary depending on who's doing the reviewing at that point in time.

Alternatively, wait until you have 2000 rep to be able to do the edit directly, without going through the suggested edits review queue.

Comment: The reject reason you mention doesn't really apply to this topic. Edits that add the author's own content or explanation to the post aren't "addressing" the author and certainly don't belong as a comment or another answer. Such an address would consist of "you should merge the contents of that comment with your answer/question".

Comment: @TylerH Excellent point. That echos my feeling about that reject reason and why it felt out of place in my own edit review that I am referring to. Yet, it was still a 3/2 vote where two reviewers rejected my edit with that reason.

Comment: *The reject reason you mention doesn't really apply to this topic.* @TylerH - It applies because that's the reason given when edits like this get rejected, which seems to happen 50% of the time. The idea that we should be adding content from the OP's comments into their posts (if it's important) is definitely not something most of the edit reviewers agree with.

Comment: @BSMP Then 50% of these edit rejections are rejected for incorrect/inaccurate reasons.